# jquery ui Dialog get data from other file

Tags: php

I try to get data from other php file in show up on jquery dialog box 
this is my code:

```
    var url = $('.exampleLink').attr('href'); 

    var $modalDialog = $('<div/>')
    .dialog({
        resizable: true,
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: false
    });

    $(function () {
        $('.exampleLink').on('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $modalDialog.load(url);
            $modalDialog.dialog("open");
        });
    });



 <a href="call.php?a=2" class="exampleLink"  >Test</a>


    <a href="call.php?a=3" class="exampleLink" >other test</a>
```

but the issue it is not show up by the element a is keep give if the `a = 2` when I click on the both link.